# Add an item in Finder's contextual menu with Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, contextmenu, finder, popupmenu

In Cocoa on Mac, I would like to add a menu item in the Finder's popup menu that comes when I right-click on a file or a folder, and having this item pointing to a function in my app.
How can I achieve this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is [CocoaDev: StandardService](http://cocoadev.com/StandardService). It outlines what you are trying to accomplish and they give some source code to follow such as the [MakingServices](http://cocoadev.com/MakingServices) example.

2015 Update: As of Yosemite, Apple includes an extension called [Finder Sync](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH15-SW1) which allows you to accomplish most of what a Service used to do.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lucas ! PlugIns do indeed not seem to work under cocoa-64 bits.

Comment: Despite following these examples, or event Apple's published ones, I can't get any Service published...

Comment: @Lucas thanks. But http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628574/how-to-include-a-field-to-an-app-on-mac?noredirect=1#comment38171792_24628574 is about making a field, which when clicked launch an application